# jQuery, deixar de executar funções consoante tamanho da janela, também no resize

Tags: jquery, funções, multiple, resize

Estou a trabalhar num site que chama ficheiros JS externos. O problema é que quando gostava que algumas funções de deixassem de correr em desktop quando `$(window).width() < 800` e vice-versa:

Link dos ficheiros JS/CSS externos:
HTML tag HEAD:

```
...

<link rel="stylesheet" media='screen and (min-width: 801px)' href ="css/styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media='screen and (max-width: 800px)' href ="css/stylesMob.css">


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/desktopLayout.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mobileLayout.js"></script>
```

desktopLayout.js:

```
var resolucao = $(window).width() > 800 ? 'desktop' : 'mobile';
$(window).resize(function(){
    resolucao = $(window).width() > 800 ? 'desktop' : 'mobile';
    console.log(resolucao);
});

...
//funções todas aqui
...
function slide4Slider() {

if (resolucao != 'desktop') return;

$("#photosSlide4 > div:eq(0) img:gt(0)").fadeOut(0);
$("#photosSlide4 > div:eq(1) img:gt(0)").fadeOut(0);
$("#photosSlide4 > div:eq(2) img:gt(0)").fadeOut(0);

setInterval(function() { 
    $('#photosSlide4 > div:eq(0) img:eq(0)').fadeOut(800).next().fadeIn(300).end().appendTo('#photosSlide4 > div:eq(0)');
    $('#photosSlide4 > div:eq(1) img:eq(0)').fadeOut(800).next().fadeIn(300).end().appendTo('#photosSlide4 > div:eq(1)');
    $('#photosSlide4 > div:eq(2) img:eq(0)').fadeOut(800).next().fadeIn(300).end().appendTo('#photosSlide4 > div:eq(2)');
},  3000);

}

function runSiteDesktop() {

   phrasesMarginsRandomSLide1();
   pizzasSlider3Animations();
   navSlider3HoverPhrase();
   arrowsLeftRightSlide();
   sizingAndRisizing();
   navBarAnimation();
   contactFancyBox();
   logoAnimation();
   navBarSlider();
   scrollEvents();
   slide4Slider();

}

$(document).ready(function() {
    runSiteDesktop();
});
```

Este efeito nota-se principalmente nas funções `phrasesMarginsRandomSLide1();` (slide1), `slide4Slider();`(slide4) e `arrowsLeftRightSlide();` (navegação left/right nas setas laterais).

Tendo em conta que eu não faço ideia do troço responsável por isso aqui fica o [site](http://iwanttobesanta.com/Touch_and_pizza/) para uma melhor análise, isto pode-se verificar na animação de frases da página inicial após um resize qualquer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema é que remover a tag `script` do HTML e o seu conteudo não remove o script da memória. Portanto quando o seu resize correr vai estar a juntar novo código em cima do antigo que fica em memória. Fiz um exemplo aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/wg2cdur2/ (repare na consola quando carrega no botão);

Se precisa ter um sistema responsivo que mude o código para o mesmo utilizador que faça um resize então vai ter de ter uma flag indica qual o código a ser corrido.

Sugestão:

```
var resolucao = screen.width > 800 ? 'desktop' : 'mobile';
$(window).resize(function(){
    resolucao = screen.width > 800 ? 'desktop' : 'mobile';
});
```

E depois dentro de cada função, event handler e outras partes de código que sõ diferentes entre *mobile* e *desktop* esta função faz `return` ou seja não continua a execução dessa linha.

```
if (resolucao != 'mobile') return;  // usar esta verificação em código mobile
if (resolucao != 'desktop') return;  // usar esta verificação em código desktop
```

Comment: Obrigado @Sergio, quando dizes `return`, é return de o quê? Essa verificação é feita onde mesmo? já pus exactamente como está aí mas não resultou. Fiz update do código em cima e também upload

Comment: Ou seja, deve ficar em memória mesmo assim, porque mesmo que eu reduza a janela para `< 800` (mobile) as funções continuam a correr, embora já sem o css

Comment: @Miguel expliquei mal, corrigi. O que sugiro é que carregues o script do mobile e desktop, **mas** em cada função deves ter a verificação que coloquei em cima para esse código não ser corrido se estiver na resolução errada para esse trecho de código.

Comment: já não duplica, mas fiz um exemplo em cima com a função `slide4slider`, a função continua a correr num resize para window < 800, se fizeres scroll cá para baixo vez o slide fadeIn/out a correr ainda

Comment: @Miguel é o slide que está a correr na div `#clouds2`?

Comment: não, é o que está no slider 4 (partilha), que no resize para < 800 vai ficar lá em baixo, e podes ver que continua